# How to check two conditions using an enum in ternary operator?

Tags: java, enums, ternary-operator

I have an enum:

```
public enum GSProccesingType {
    bigCover,
    cover,
    other
}
```

Such condition if the cover comes then that is selected `FileStoreUtils.coverFileName`, if the `bigCover` comes then that is chosen `bigCoverFileName` else "04d.png"

I cannot make a short condition for cover and bigCover

```
final String fileName = proccesingType == cover  ? FileStoreUtils.coverFileName : "%04d.png";

final String fileName2 = proccesingType == bigCover ? FileStoreUtils.bigCoverFileName : "04d.png";
```

How do I connect two lines to one to be right?

Comment: Please post your code here as text

Comment: Use `if elseif` statement or `nested ?:` operator.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested ternary operator like this:

```
final String fileName = proccesingType == cover  ? 
                            FileStoreUtils.coverFileName : 
                            (proccesingType == bigCover ? FileStoreUtils.bigCoverFileName : "%04d.png");
```

, but this is hard to read. I would suggest creating a method for that:

```
private String getFilename(GSProccesingType type) {
    switch(type) {
        case cover: return FileStoreUtils.coverFileName;
        case bigCover : return FileStoreUtils.bigCoverFileName ;
        default: return "%04d.png";
    }
}
```

this is longer, but much easier to read and understand.

I also suggest following [generally accepted naming conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.4-constant-names), and using ALL_UPPERCASE for enum constants.